# Where can I find Google API JavaScript Library source code repository?

Tags: google-api, google-api-client, google-api-js-client

I've opened [Google APIs Client Library for browser JavaScript, aka gapi](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client) just to find out that

> Note: This repo does not contain the source code for the `gapi` client.

Where can I find a repository for `gapi` aka *Google APIs Client Library for browser JavaScript*. I know I can get it from `https://apis.google.com/js/api.js`. But I need a repo, I want to learn it, and examine it, and debug it.

Comment: This might not be what you are looking for but perhaps it could help. https://apis.google.com/js/client.js